# Вопрос по работе цикла while внутри метода

Tags: java, ооп, while

Оригинал кода тут:
https://gist.github.com/EugeneWenew/381d5ef9bb5fcb6a63ef9b4debb96ee8

В общем: есть крестики-нолики. Есть метод получения координат от пользователя. Есть метод простановки этих координат на поле.

```
/**
* Класс игрока
*/
package TicTacToe;

public class Player {
    private int id;
    private static int count = 0;
    private String name;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    Player() {
        count++;
        id = count;
    }

    Player(String name) {
        this();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player{" +
                "id " + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

/**
* Менеджер игроков
*/
package TicTacToe;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlayerManager {
    ArrayList<Player> players;

    PlayerManager() {
        players = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void addPlayer(String name) {
        Player player = new Player(name);
        players.add(player);
    }



    Player getFirstPlayer() {
        return players.get(0);
    }

    Player getSecondPlayer() {
        return players.get(1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PlayerManager{" +
                ", players=" + players +
                '}';
    }
}


/**
 * класс игровое поле
 */
public class Field {
    char[][] field;                                     //видимое поле 1
    ArrayList<Integer> space;                         //альтернативное внутреннее поле 2
    private Point point;
    Scanner scanner;
    Player player;

    Field() {
        char[][] field = new char[3][3];                // 1
        this.field = field;
        space = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    void fillTheField() {                               // 1
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                this.field[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }
    }

    void fillTheSpace() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            space.add(i);
        }
    }


    void printFields() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(this.field[i][j] + "\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.out.print(space.get(i) + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    void madeTheMark(Field field, Point point, Player player) {
        if (player.getId() == 1) {
            field.markO(point.getX(), point.getY());
        } else {
            field.markX(point.getX(), point.getY());
        }
    }

    void markX(int x, int y) {
        this.field[x][y] = 'X';
    }

    void markO(int x, int y) {
        this.field[x][y] = '0';
    }

    Point getCellCoords() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = -2;
        while ((i < 0) | (i > 2)) {
            System.out.println("Введите позицию по горизонтали(от 0 до 2):");
            i = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
        }

        int j = -3;
        while ((i < 0) | (i > 2)) {
            System.out.println("Введите позицию по вертикали(от 0 до 2):");
            j = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        Point point = new Point(j, i);
        return point;
    }

    boolean checkCells(char[][] field) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (((field[i][0]) == 'X') & ((field[i][1]) == 'X') & ((field[i][2]) == 'X')) {
                return true;
            } else if ((((field[0][i]) == 'X')) & ((field[1][i]) == 'X') & ((field[2][i]) == 'X')) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (((field[0][0]) == 'X') & ((field[1][1]) == 'X') & ((field[2][2]) == 'X')) {
            return true;
        } else if (((field[2][0]) == 'X') & ((field[1][1]) == 'X') & ((field[0][2]) == 'X')) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (((field[i][0]) == '0') & ((field[i][1]) == '0') & ((field[i][2]) == '0')) {
                return true;
            } else if ((((field[0][i]) == '0')) & ((field[1][i]) == '0') & ((field[2][i]) == '0')) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (((field[0][0]) == '0') & ((field[1][1]) == '0') & ((field[2][2]) == '0')) {
            return true;
        } else if (((field[2][0]) == '0') & ((field[1][1]) == '0') & ((field[0][2]) == '0')) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


}


/**
*Основной цикл
*/

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main start = new Main();
        start.runGame();
    }

    void runGame() {
        PlayerManager manager = new PlayerManager();
        manager.addPlayer(playerInvitation());
        manager.addPlayer(playerInvitation());
        Field plate = new Field();
        plate.fillTheField();               //инициализация поля отображаемого для игроков
        plate.fillTheSpace();               //поле для вычислений
        plate.printFields();
        mainCycle(plate, manager);
    }

    void mainCycle(Field plate, PlayerManager manager) {
        do {
            nextTurn(manager.getFirstPlayer());
            plate.madeTheMark(plate, plate.getCellCoords(), manager.getFirstPlayer());
            plate.printFields();
            if (plate.checkCells(plate.field)) {
                System.out.println("Победил игрок " + manager.getFirstPlayer().getName());
                break;
            }
            nextTurn(manager.getSecondPlayer());
            plate.madeTheMark(plate, plate.getCellCoords(), manager.getSecondPlayer());
            plate.printFields();
            if (plate.checkCells(plate.field)) {
                System.out.println("Победил игрок " + manager.getSecondPlayer().getName());
                break;
            }
        } while (!plate.checkCells(plate.field));
    }

    String playerInvitation() {
        System.out.println("Введите имя игрока: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        return name;
    }

    void nextTurn(Player player) {
        System.out.println("Ходит игрок " + player.getName());
    }
}
```

**Описание проблемы:**

При получении координат, я попытался создать ОГРАНИЧИТЕЛЬ на принимаемое число:

```
while ((i < 0) | (i > 2)) {
```

, т.е. чтобы координата не выходила за пределы поля.
При этом, чтобы условие изначально выполнялось, проинициализированы переменные:

```
 int i = -2;
     int j = -3;
```

При работе цикла WHILE, при введении правильных координат (т.е. 0 или 1 или 2), цикл завершается.
***И по идее код должен выполняться дальше.***
Но получается, что я получаю первую координату, а вторая координата УЖЕ ЗАДАНА числом:

```
int j = -3;
```

И я натыкаюсь на:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -3 out of bounds for length 3

at TicTacToe.Field.markO(Field.java:65)
at TicTacToe.Field.madeTheMark(Field.java:54)
at TicTacToe.Main.mainCycle(Main.java:27)
at TicTacToe.Main.runGame(Main.java:21)
at TicTacToe.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Почему **НЕ НАЧИНАЕТ** выполняться **второй ЦИКЛ WHILE**   ?

Т.е. почему метод сразу принимает заданное число, заместо ПРИЕМА координаты от пользователя ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы с Вами уже говорили о недостаточной внимательности.

```
    int j = -3;
  //while ((i < 0) | (i > 2)) {
    while ((j < 0) | (j > 2)) {
```

---

Здесь не требуется полного вычисления всех операндов булевского выражения:

```
    while (j < 0 || j > 2) {
```

Comment: Да, говорили. У меня это обычное дело. Извините.

Comment: @Eugene_Venev `if (this.player == players.get(0)) {`

Comment: @Eugene_Venev Бессмысленно гадать, не видя текущей версии кода. Задайте новый вопрос.