# Проблема с проверкой значения в методе и рекурсией

Tags: java, ооп, рекурсия, while, equals

В общем - есть метод, получения чисел от пользователя, есть метод проверки чисел. Числа должны быть получены в некотором диапазоне.

Если кратко - то это проверка вводимой ячейки для крестиков-ноликов.
Начало тут :[Проблема с использованием ключевого слова this](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223502/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-this/1223509#1223509)

конструктор пары чисел:

```
public class Point {
    int x, y;
public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Point point = (Point) o;
    return x == point.x &&
            y == point.y;
}
```

Метод запроса от пользователя:

```
  Point setCellCoords() {
        Point point = null;
        do {
            point = getCellCoords();
        } while (checkPoint(point));
        space.add(point);
        return point;
    }

      Point getCellCoords() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = -2;
        int j = -3;
        while (((i < 0) || (i > 2)) & ((j < 0) || (j > 2))) {
            System.out.println("Введите позицию по горизонтали(от 0 до 2):");
            i = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Введите позицию по вертикали(от 0 до 2):");
            j = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        Point point = new Point(j, i);
        return point;
    }
```

Метод проверки чисел:

```
boolean checkPoint(Point point) {
    for (Point spaces : space) {
        if ((point.getX() == spaces.getX()) & (point.getY() == spaces.getX())) {
            System.out.println("Уже было:");
            System.out.println("Вводите повторно!");
            getCellCoords();                            //<<<------ рекурсия
            return true;
        } else {
            space.add(point);                  //<<<-------поле ДУБЛЕР
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Вопросы:

1. вообще возможно использовать **== , equals, compareTo** в данном случае, заместо
   point.getX() == spaces.getX(), по типу point.equals(spaces)?
   equals у меня переопределен в классе Point, но проверяются ссылки на point а не содержимое point, поэтому я не смог применить его. Если возможно, какая должна быть конструкция ?
2. **Как ликвидировать рекурсию, при этом оставив бесконечную проверку получаемых чисел на уникальность**?
   Я добавляю УНИКАЛЬНЫЕ числа в arraylist, чтобы по нему проводить проверку на уникальность.
   Я пытался использовать конструкцию do-while, где
   while(checkPoint(point));, при этом сам point создавался в теле do, но IJ не позволила мне это сделать. Т.е. я хочу создать point и тут же его проверить на уникальность.
   Возможно мне стоит использовать не Arraylist ?
   Дело в том, что в методе сheckPoint происходит заполнение поля-дублёра уникальными значениями. Оно используется для выявления НИЧЬЕЙ в игре, когда все 9 значений будут добавлены в массив.  Т.е. смыслом всей конструкции является заполнение этого поля уникальными значениями.

Comment: 1) в классе Point переопределите методы equals и hashcode 2) после этого для хранения уникальных точек используйте HashSet

Comment: `(point.getY() == spaces.getX())` тут у вас вероятно ошибка

Comment: чтобы убрвть рекурсию, вам нужен третий метод, который сначала считвате точку первы методом, потом проверит её уникальность вторым.

Comment: @tym32167 , подскажите, я вот такую конструкцию пытаюсь

`Point setCellCoords() {
        do {
            Point point = getCellCoords();
        }while (!checkPoint(point));
    }`

но whilе не видит point. Почему?

Comment: Ну вы можете объявить переменную до конструкции, например `Point point = null; do {...}while(...)`

Comment: Я ничего не понял в вашем комментарии последнем.

Comment: Извините. Добавил тело метода в пост.
В методе 
Point setCellCoords() {
если присваивать в начале тела point = null, то он все тело метода Null и на выходе тоже null.
IJ мне так говорит.

Comment: кака разница, что вам IJ говорит, вы код запускали? С ним есть пргоблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так :

```
@lombok.Value
public class Point {
    
    private final static int RANGE_MAX = 2, RANGE_MIN = 0;

    private int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        if (range(x) && range(y)) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        } 
        else throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Out of range : " + RANGE_MIN + " : " + RANGE_MAX);
    }
    
    private boolean range(int numb) {
        return (numb >= RANGE_MIN) && (numb <= RANGE_MAX);
    }
    
}

class CoordinatInput {
    
        private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        private final Set<Point> space = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        
        public Set<Point> setCellCoords(Integer spaceSize) {
            while(space.size()!=spaceSize){
                addCellCoords().ifPresent(point -> {
                    if (!space.add(point)) System.out.println("Уже было, вводите повторно!");
                });
            }
            return space;
        }
    
        private Optional<Point> addCellCoords() {
            
            try {
                System.out.println("Введите позицию по горизонтали(от 0 до 2):");
                Integer x = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Введите позицию по вертикали(от 0 до 2):");
                Integer y = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
                return Optional.of(new Point(x, y));
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {            
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                return Optional.empty();
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("Incorrect user input (numbers only)");
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        }
        
    }
```